# Issue with stripos and digits

Tags: php, string, url, get, stripos

for example I have current link on which I want to redirect:

```
   if(stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'post.php?post=5')!==false){
   //redirect
   }
```

But if the post ID would be post=55 it will redirect too... How to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use $_GET variable?

```
if (isset($_GET['post']) && $_GET['post'] == 5) {
  ...
}
```